# proftpd: copying uploaded files to an additional directory

Tags: synchronization, upload, ftp

Using proftpd, is there a good way to automatically synchronise uploaded files from the upload directory to some other directory?

Our layout ends up a bit like this:

```
~/ftp/some/path <-- Files are uploaded here
~/some/other/path/not/accessible/via/ftp <-- But also need to be here after uploading
```

Is there a good way to do this automatically, or do I have to tell anyone uploading files to upload twice, and open up an additional directory (containing data we cannot redistribute)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tool such as [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) can act upon files once they have finished uploading, including copying them to another location.